# Why do we care whether a functor is representable?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, category-theory

In the algebraic geometry textbook by Görtz and Wedhorn, the authors prove that several common functors are representable. For example, [the Grassmannian functors are representable](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/089R).

Beyond being cute category-theoretical facts, why does this matter? What practical benefits come form knowing that certain functors are representable? Does this observation simplify or make possible the proofs of certain theorems, for example? This is perhaps too broad a question, so I should mention I'm mostly interested in the context of algebraic geometry.

Comment: This is a very weird question. Functors were introduced in geometry as a way of splitting the proof that some geometric object exists in two parts: first, one constructed a generalized object and then one shows that the object is in fact a classical object. This is exactly the same idea as that behind the role played by distributions in PDEs: one invents distributions so as to be able to show more easily that a certain equation does have solutions in some generalized sense, and then one works more to show that those generalized solutions are in fact actual, classical solutions.

Comment: An grand example of this is the proof that Hilbert schemes exist.

Comment: That representability may have come to be regarded as a «cute category-theoretical fact» is a reflection of the IMO unsatisfactory way in which we are teaching geometry :-|

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks for your comment. Could you give an example of that approach to proving a geometric object exists? I think that is a suitable answer, and I would be happy to accept it if you posted it as one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functors are hard. Schemes are much easier. If a functor $F$ is representable by $X$ then it's values at $T$ is completely described by maps from $T$ to $X$. For example, for a field $K$, you get a bijection $F(Spec K) = Hom(Spec K,X)$, so $F(Spec K)$ is in bijection with the $K$-points of $X$, so you can study your abstract functor by studying the scheme, which is much easier to study - the theory of schemes is very well developed. Far less can be said about general functors. For example, schemes can be described by *equations*. If you can find equations for your scheme then that will often tell you a lot of information about the stuff your functor is parametrizing which otherwise would be very difficult to obtain. Some other useful aspects: the dimension of the representing scheme tells you roughly how many ``parameters'' is needed to specify an element of your functor. If $X$ is a curve then the genus roughly tells you how many $K$-rational points it has if $K$ is a global field.

Comment: Your second statement is a little misleading. It was actually the study of $X_0(N)$, which is never representable, which constituted most of Mazur's proof.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Hmm I guess you're right. I do remember only seeing $X_0(N)$'s when reading it a couple years back, though when I was writing this I thought surely $Y_1(N)$ and $Y(N)$ must show up *somewhere*, but I guess if you want to prove nonexistence of torsion, it suffices to consider coarse moduli schemes.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the first sentence. I much prefer using the functor to derive facts about the scheme.

Comment: @Hoot well that's because the scheme is *defined* by the functor, so of course any facts about the scheme necessarily come from properties of the functor. But once you know your functor is representable, and once you can translate *some* facts about $F$ into facts $A,B,C$ about $X$, then the fact that $F$ is represented by $X$ lets you use the abundant existing theory of schemes to derive other facts about $X$ (and hence $F$) from $A,B,C$.

Comment: @Hoot While this is true in some situations, I don't think it's true always. For example, while smoothness is easy to encode in the functor, notions like 'finite type' are not (I guess you can say that finite presentation means commutes with filtered colimits?). And, basic things like Noetherian become very annoying to phrase in that language.

And, even then, even when it's nicer to write down a definition functorially it's often easier to intuit this definition geometrically (smoothness maybe being a rare counterexample).

Comment: @Hoot It's a two way street. If schemes weren't easier then functors, then everything which is true of schemes would be obviously true of algebraic spaces.

Comment: Right, right, the tone didn't really come out as I intended. I just don't want the OP to get the impression that the functor is the bad actor. The answer is of course good. Illusie has some quote about the language of representable functors allowing functors to have geometry that I think summarizes the situation perfectly. I should find time to just copy that. I think "two-way street" is a good way to sum it up as well.

Comment: @Hoot Yes, please!

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) two aspects. First, a functor which is known to be representable, has nice categorical properties, for example representable functors are trivially continous, that is they preserve all limits.

But if we know an isomorphism $F\cong\hom(X,-)$, this does not only tell us something about $F$. It tells us something about the representing object $X$. In fact, by the Yoneda lemma, it tells us *everyting* about the representing object $X$: An isomorphism $\hom(X,-)\cong\hom(Y,-)$ yields a unique isomorphism $X\cong Y$. This kind of reasoning is used all the time in algebraic geometry (and everywhere else in maths).