Motivation for representability in algebraic geometry
I am studying the construction of the global spectrum of a quasi-coherent sheaf of algebras and its relationship with affine morphisms. I find this construction difficult to motivate.
Given a category ( C ), one way to understand the Yoneda lemma is to recognize that an object ( c ) can be identified with its functor $( \text{Hom}(c, -) )$ or $( \text{Hom}(-, c) )$. This perspective provides a useful definition for the product and direct sum of two objects, which generalizes the definitions found in specific categories like sets, groups, and rings.
My question : is there a general motivation for studying the representability of specific functors, especially in modern algebraic geometry and algebra unlike from what i study in differential geometry, it seems that many constructions are expressed as representations of particular functors.

Here are two related questions that have been asked on MSE over the years: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610050/what-is-the-geometric-meaning-of-representability https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519400/why-do-we-care-whether-a-functor-is-representable Do either of those help you?

@KReiser, thanks for your answer; If I understand correctly, functors can be thought of as elements of a larger space that contains schemes, while representability is akin to asking whether the functor belongs to a smaller space. However, I'm still unsure why we care for example about the functor of quasi-coherent algebras and what studying a functor truly means.

The categorical background is the following: Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category, then its presheaf category $\mathsf{PSh}(\mathscr{C})$ is the free cocompletion of $\mathscr{C}$: We start with $\mathscr{C}$ and freely add all possible colimits to the category - and in this identification the objects from $\mathscr{C}$ become precisely the representables. This can be made precise with the universal property
$$ y^* : \mathsf{Fun}^{\mathrm{colim}}(\mathsf{PSh}(\mathscr{C}), \mathscr{D}) \xrightarrow{\ \simeq \ } \mathsf{Fun}(\mathscr{C}, \mathscr{D}) $$
for all cocomplete categories $\mathscr{D}$ where $\mathsf{Fun}^{\mathrm{colim}}$ means colimit-preserving functors.
So we started with our world $\mathscr{C}$ which may not be so well-behaved (e.g. schemes or manifolds which do not have all colimits) and added all colimits, i.e. some meaning of gluing, to it in a universal way. On the other hand, we were really interested in $\mathscr{C}$ in the beginning, so now we have to go the other way: Given any presheaf $F \in \mathsf{PSh}(\mathscr{C})$, is it representable? In other words, is it an object from $\mathscr{C}$? In the example of schemes: Is this abstract presheaf $F$ that we obtained from freely taking colimits actually a scheme?

Thank you for your response. This concept looks similar to the algebraic closure of a field or the completion of a metric space. This question is somewhat broad, but to understand why we care about a particular presheaf, what properties should one consider? For instance, if someone is interested in an object within the presheaf category, such as the category of manifolds or topological spaces, what specific properties should they focus on?

@Kaneki1013 As you guessed, this question is too broad and depends on the context. This is a common theme in mathematics: We add more stuff to our universe so that it becomes better behaved and now some more interesting objects arise (either for its own sake or to study the original objects). For example, in algebraic geometry, there are certain moduli stacks which may not be written as schemes, but only as a correct higher version of a sheaf (which is a refined version of a presheaf).
